# background-color doesn't work on dynamically inserted element

Tags: javascript, css, background-color, mathjax

I'am trying to set a floating div label to specific part of MathJax equation.
That's why I must insert HTML element describing label dynamically into the code, because elements in which I want to insert the code are generated in runtime.

I am able to find the part and add floating div as label, problem is that for some reason I am not able to change the background color.

I tried plenty of different ways ("Insert it in css file, have in style when element is inserted, add it later by js) and css tags ("background", "background-color"). The style appears in element
[message html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32sqz.png)
but background color doesnt change
[message appearence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6KWk.png).

```
let els = document.getElementById("id").getElementsByClassName("mjx-mstyle")
for(let i = 0; i < els.length; i++){
  if(window.getComputedStyle(els[i]).color.indexOf("rgb(206, 15, 33)") >= 0 ){
    (els[i]).setAttribute("style", "color: rgb(206, 15, 33); background-color: navy; position: relative");
    (els[i]).innerHTML += 
    '<div id="message1" style="position: absolute; top: -10px; width: 100px; color: black; background-color: black">This is my text</div>' -;
    (els[i]).setAttribute("onmouseover", "document.getElementById('message1').style.display = 'block'");
    (els[i]).setAttribute("onmouseout", "document.getElementById('message1').style.display = 'none'");
  }
```

UPDATE:

Fiddle can be found here https://jsfiddle.net/Lqn0afxm/37/ . Message is hidden under the "x". It will appear on mouseover.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: use `!important` : `background-color: navy!important;`

Comment: please share the html code

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or code snippet on here - hard to see what's going on without a (non)-working version

Comment: I added a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lqn0afxm/37/, message is hidden under "x". 
it will appear on mouseover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code outer div has zero height, set height for div otherwise you can also set overflow to hidden

Comment: Unfortunately no diff.

Comment: I added a fiddle. message is hidden under "x". It will appear on mouseover

Comment: your code outer div renders zero height, set height for div otherwise you can also set overflow to hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: 
The problem was, that div inherited height of 0px from some part of MathJax. 
The text overflew so it was visible, but the rest of the div was invisible due to its zero volume.